# Responsive Filemanager Thumbnails not showing

Tags: thumbnails, responsive-filemanager

Using Responsive Filemanager 9.11.3
Thumbnails are not showing/blank in dialog window (GUI). In ftp thumbnails pictures are okay created successfully. Folder "thumbs" permission 755 files permission 644. i changed to 755 still not showing up in dialog window. thumb sizes are 2.4kb

Answer (score 3):

I've finally found full solution:
It's all because of `$lazy_loading_enabled` variable. On first load it is `true`. In `dialog.php` line 621 just set its value to false

```
$lazy_loading_enabled = false;
```

Now it should work. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, if you resize that `iframe` or the `div` where responsive file manager is, then thumbnails will show up...

Work around:

- set `iframe` height/width to be `101%`
- set `onLoad` attribute to `iframe` that will resize `iframe` width/height to `100%`

Example:

```
<script>
function loadThumbs() {
    var rfm = document.getElementById("rfm");
    rfm.style.height = "100%"
}
</script>
<iframe id="rfm" onload="loadThumbs()" src="..." style="height: 101%; width: 100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem still with the newest version. Worked fine on localhost, but once uploaded to server thumbnails disappeared.

I was able to fix the problem by editting the `config.php` file and removing default value of hidden_files from
`'hidden_files' => array( 'config.php' )`
to
`'hidden_files' => array()`